# Are there two Zenos?

Tags: discussion

[zeno](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zeno) [zeno-of-elea](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zeno-of-elea)

> Users with more than 1250 reputation and a total answer score of 5 or more on the tag, can **suggest** tag synonyms. Users with a total answer score (total upvotes minus total downvotes) of 5 or more on the tag, can vote for tag synonyms.

It's clear that creation of tag synonyms is a very dangerous feature, but the restriction of “a total answer score of 5” for just making a *mere* ***suggestion*** seems a bit off.

Does this *really* reduce stupid suggestions **in the case of philosophy.SE?** You don't need an answer score of +5 on the proposed synonym tag, after all. (Of course this won't be changed, it's deeply embedded in the system).

EDIT: okay there's Zeno of Citium :-D

Comment: To be honest, I find the requirements also a bit absurd. And we're not the only ones: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103211/can-we-allow-7-5k-users-to-suggest-tag-synonyms-without-a-score-of-5-in-the-tag . It seems the only way is to pester mods about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps the score of 5 isn't really necessary, but considering that we [very rarely](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms) have to add synonyms there isn't really a problem: bring it up on meta (as you did) and one of the mods can add the synonym.

I have merged [zeno](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zeno) into [zeno-of-elea](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zeno-of-elea) (not the other way around, because this is more specific) and added a synonym from the first to the latter. I also added the following [tag usage guidance](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tags/zeno-of-elea/info) (which you or anyone can edit and improve):

> Zeno of Elea (commonly known as Zeno) was a pre-Socratic Greek philosopher. He is well-known for Zeno's paradoxes. Not to be confused with Zeno of Citium, a lesser-known Hellenistic philosopher.